# Why does output of & operator with any logic operation doesn't give any output in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bitwise-operators

```
puts "Hello World"

scores = {"biology" => ['unit_test','final_exam'],
  "maths" => ['quiz','class_participation','final_exam']
}

x =  (scores["biology"] & %w[flying_test])

puts "result of x && scores[\"biology\"].any? => #{x && scores["biology"].any?}"# Why does this return true? 

y = scores["maths"] & %w[quiz]
z = scores["maths"].any?
puts "result of scores[\"maths\"] & %w[quiz] => #{y}" # returns true
puts "result of scores[\"maths\"].any? => #{z}" # return true
puts "result of y && z => #{y && z}"

puts "******"
puts "Clubbing all conditions, returns no output, why? it is actually evluates to (true || true), right"
puts ( (scores["biology"].any? && (scores["biology"] & %w[flying_test])) ||
       (scores["maths"].any? && (scores["maths"] & %w[quiz])) )


# But when above two sub-conditions are swapped puts print the value as true
puts "$$$$$$$"
puts ((scores["biology"] & %w[flying_test]) && scores["biology"].any?) ||
((scores["maths"] & %w[quiz]) && scores["maths"].any?)


puts "cross check"
# puts (1 == 1).any?
```

https://onlinegdb.com/YBmzutZOj - you can execute here

Comment: Note the difference between the `&&` operator (boolean AND) and the `&` operator (set intersection in this case).

Comment: `&&` in Ruby does not return `true`/`false`, it returns the last evaluated value. `a && b` contains expression `a` and expression `b`. `a` is always evaluated. If `a` evaluates to a falsy value (`nil` or `false`) the expression is short circuited and the result of `a` is returned. If `a` evaluates to a truthy value (not `false` or `nil`) then expression `b` is evaluated and the result of `b` is returned. Here are some examples: `true && true #=> true`, `true && 1 #=> 1`, `1 && 'Hello World!' #=> "Hello World!"`, `false && 1 #=> false`, `nil && 1 #=> nil`, `2 && nil #=> nil`

Answer (score 0):

what are you actually trying to do with your "&"?

simplifying examples:

```
puts ( scores["biology"] & %w[flying_test] )
```

are you trying to check that the object exists, and only return the object, ala:

```
if scores["biology"].include?('flying_test')
```

or are you trying to do an addition:

```
scores["biology"] + %w[flying_test]
```

or return your list if there are no scores?

```
scores["biology"] || %w[flying_test]
```

...

or is it that you want to include the "&" as part of the test of what to return:

```
puts (scores['biology'].any? && scores['biology'].include?('flying_test') && %w[flying_test]) ||
     (scores['maths'].any? && scores['maths'].include?('quiz') && %w[quiz])
```

or possibly, more like (closer to your style of coding):

```
puts (scores["biology"] & %w[flying_test]).any? && (scores["biology"] & %w[flying_test]) ||
      scores["maths"] & %w[quiz]
```

?

Comment: just a note to whoever downvoted, the question as it stands is unclear.  I have proposed several solutions that do actually do what he could want, however I believe that the last one of these is what he's actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` returns the second operand, if both operands are `truthy`, and in `ruby` the empty list is `truthy`.

In your particular case, `x =  (scores["biology"] & %w[flying_test])` evaluates to the empty list `[]`, so `x && scores["biology"].any?` actually evaluates to `[] && true`, so `true`.

Also, in

```
puts ( (scores["biology"].any? && (scores["biology"] & %w[flying_test])) ||
       (scores["maths"].any? && (scores["maths"] & %w[quiz])) )
```

the first operand also evaluates to an empty list, so the entire `||` operation evaluates to the empty list `[]`. Doing a `puts []` results in a no output being generated.

Comment: Although I agree with the answer I have the feeling that *"the first operand also evaluates to an empty list"* could use some additional explanation, since OP seems to think that `&&` returns either `true` or `false`. Just adding the evaluation steps might make things more clear. `scores["biology"].any? && (scores["biology"] & %w[flying_test])` -> `true && []` -> `[]`